# Would a chunky mantel allow me to mount my TV above a wood burner?

Tags: fireplace

I would like a woodburner with a twin flue install to take the flue outside. If I put a chunky mantel above it, can I then safely mount my TV on the wall without heat killing it?

When I say chunky I mean 2-3 railway sleepers depth from wall.

[image: Sketch of woodburner with TV above]

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your drawing:

- code may very well not allow a wooden mantel directly above a woodburning stove like that. Woodburning stoves get extremely hot. Check the spec's on your stove to determine the minimum clearance from combustibles.
- Soot. No matter how hard you try, a woodburning stove is likely to kick a bit of soot into the room now and again. Not the best for TV screens.
- your neck may not like the angle. Lots of people put TVs above fireplaces and they look really great in magazines, but are often the worst possible place to actually place a TV.

(BTW, very nice sketch! That's always a great asset to questions here.)

Comment: Besides, it will suck to watch dark parts of a movie while the fire burns below, since your pupils will shrink due to the fire's brightness and you won't see much on the screen...

Comment: If the light from the fire is not too bright, it could act as a [bias light](http://biaslighting.blogspot.com/) and actually improve contrast on the TV. Though bias lighting is typically white so it doesn't disrupt color rendition.

Comment: @RenéRoth unless you're watching...Firestarter. Or maybe Backdraft. Then perhaps the fire would enhance. :)